# Method not allowed error 405 post ajax request to post route

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5, routes

I am getting a method not allowed 405 error when am trying to post to database through ajax post request to post route. Please Help

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } 
});

$.ajax({
    url: '{{url("HeatMapCoordinates")}}',
    data:{
        "finalPointArray" : finalPointsMap,
        "tourId":tourId,
        "picWidth":picWidth,
        "picName":picName
    },
    async:true,
    type:'post',
    success:function(response){
        console.log("coordinates sent");
        finalPointsMap=[];
        pointsMap=[];
        pointsMap.push(initialPoint);
    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

I have also tried

```
url: '{{route("HeatMapCoordinates.store")}}',
```

But it is also not working my route is :

```
Route::resource('/HeatMapCoordinates','HeatMapCoordinatesController');
```

My Controller Function :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'tourId'     => 'required',
        'picWidth' => 'required',
        'picName'  => 'required',
        'finalPointArray'  => 'required',

    ));
...
return 'stored';
}
```

Comment: Ah! please add your **Controller** function used in this Route - I want to see it, to know more about your problem :)

Comment: sure ,just edited the question and added it

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#your_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('HeatMapCoordinates_store') }}",
   method:"POST",
   data: new FormData(this),
   dataType:'JSON',
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    console.log(data);
    // ANY CODE HERE
    $('#result').html(data.result);
   },
   error:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#result').html('No result. We have an ERROR ...');
    }
  })
 });

});
```

And Use a form like this :

```
<form method="POST" id="your_form">
    <input type="text" name="finalPointsMap">
    <input type="text" name="tourId">
    <input type="text" name="picWidth">
    <input type="text" name="picName">

    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Use this `<div>` to show results :

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

And **after** your `<head>` :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Use this **Route** :

```
Route::post('/HeatMapCoordinates/store','HeatMapCoordinatesController@store')->name('HeatMapCoordinates_store');
```

And Use This function in your **Controller** :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $validator = $this->validate($request, [
        'tourId'     => 'required',
        'picWidth' => 'required',
        'picName'  => 'required',
        'finalPointArray'  => 'required'
    ]);

    # RETURN ERRORS AS JSON
    if ($validator->fails()) {
       return response()->json([
            'result' => 'ERROR: ' // USE $validator->errors() for example ... 
        ]);
    }

    # USE YOUR INPUTS HERE, LIKE THIS 
    $id = $request->tourId;

    return response()->json([
        'result' => 'Good, ID is : '.$id
    ]);
}
```

Please tell me if it's work :)